# How to diff .odt files with difftool? kdiff3 diff outputs unreadable characters

Tags: git, diff, batch-processing, git-difftool

In git I'm trying to use `.gitattributes` to compare .odt files, libreofice writer files, with difftool.
From following this guide: http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~moy/opendocument/ I made a `.gitattributes` file .gitattributes with this:

```
*.ods diff=odf
*.odt diff=odf
*.odp diff=odf

*.ods difftool=odf
*.odt difftool=odf
*.odp difftool=odf
```

This made git diff compare the text in .odt, however when git difftool launches kdiff3 to compare the .odt files, I get this pop-up error:

```
Some input characters could not be converted to valid unicode.
You might be using the wrong codec. (e.g. UTF-8 for non UTF-8 files).
Don't save the result if unsure. Continue at your own risk.
Affected input files are in A, B.
```

...and all of the characters in the files are mumbo jumbo.

What went wrong? How do I fix this?

PS:

I don't know if this is important but I guess I haven't configured 'diff.tool', because every time I command:

```
$ git difftool
```

I get this output:

```
This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff

Viewing (1/1): 'diffexperiment.odt'
Launch 'kdiff3' [Y/n]:
```

Could that be why kdiff3 doesn't seem to work with odt2txt?

EDIT: I retried to do this with Microsoft Word documents and got a little further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023396/in-git-how-to-diff-microsoft-word-documents).

I played around with .kdiff3rc configuration... none of the options I added seemed to make the unreadable characters readable.
I changed the comparison tool to vimdiff; and when I did git difftool on microsoft word documents, vimdiff displayed a list of files ending in .xml instead of unreadable characters.

When I pushed enter on one of the files this displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  " Browsing zipfile /tmp/4LMJbj_HI I am writing something here..docx                          |<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"><Override PartName
  " Select a file with cursor and press ENTER                                                  |="/_rels/.rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/><Overr
                                                                                               |ide PartName="/word/settings.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.w
  _rels/.rels                                                                                  |ordprocessingml.settings+xml"/><Override PartName="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" ContentType=
  word/settings.xml                                                                            |"application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/><Override PartName="/word/fontTabl
  word/_rels/document.xml.rels                                                                 |e.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+x
  word/fontTable.xml                                                                           |ml"/><Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officed
  word/numbering.xml                                                                           |ocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/><Override PartName="/word/document.xml" ContentType="app
  word/styles.xml                                                                              |lication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/><Override Part
  word/document.xml                                                                            |Name="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-p
  docProps/app.xml                                                                             |roperties+xml"/><Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlfo
  docProps/core.xml                                                                            |rmats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
  [Content_Types].xml                                                                          |</Types>
```

I posted a new question on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098218/is-git-difftool-on-binaries-possible-if-so-how-does-one-configure-it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need, in addition of the `.gitattribute`, to *configure* what `odf` means:

```
git config diff.odf.textconv odt2txt
```

And you need [**`odt2txt`**](https://github.com/dstosberg/odt2txt/) (a simple converter from OpenDocument Text to plain text) in your `$PATH (Linux/Mac)` or `%PATH%` (Windows).

No need to configure `difftool`, as `kdiff3` is enough by default.
But `kdiff3` needs to open a text file, hence the need to `odt2txt` (in order to convert first the doc into a text file)

---

For more on `textconv`, see "[Performing text diffs of binary files](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_performing_text_diffs_of_binary_files)":

> Sometimes it is desirable to see the diff of a text-converted version of some binary files. For example, a word processor document can be converted to an ASCII text representation, and the diff of the text shown.
>   Even though this conversion loses some information, the resulting diff is useful for human viewing (but cannot be applied directly).
>
> The `textconv` config option is used to define a program for performing such a conversion. The program should take a single argument, the name of a file to convert, and produce the resulting text on stdout.
>
> ### Note
>
> The text conversion is generally a one-way conversion; This means that diffs generated by `textconv` are not suitable for applying.
>
> For this reason, only `git diff` and the `git log` family of commands (i.e., `log`, `whatchanged`, `show`) will perform text conversion.
>   `git format-patch` will never generate this output.
>
> If you want to send somebody a text-converted diff of a binary file (e.g., because it quickly conveys the changes you have made), you should generate it separately and send it as a comment in addition to the usual binary diff that you might send.

---

The [OP Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5491153/jack) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448260/how-to-diff-odt-files-with-difftool-kdiff3-diff-outputs-unreadable-characters/33448371#comment55799655_33448371):

> On Linux I ran in my home directory:

```
$ git config diff.odf.textconv odt2txt
```

> I had `odt2txt` installed... and I assume `odt2txt` is in `$PATH`, because when I run `$ odt2txt`, I get information on `odt2txt`.
>   However, none of those things seem to make `git diff .odt` files for some reason.
>   When I `$ git diff fileone.odt filetwo.odt`, I still get the output of Binary files fileone.odt and filetwo.odt differ instead of exactly how the text differentiates.
>   Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: On Linux I ran:

$ git config diff.odf.textconv odt2txt
in my home directory.

I had odt2txt installed ... and I assume odt2txt is in $PATH, because when I run

$ odt2txt
I get information on odt2txt.

However, none of those things seem to make git diff .odt files for some reason.

When I

$ git diff fileone.odt filetwo.odt
I still get the output of: Binary files fileone.odt and filetwo.odt differ instead of exactly how the text differentiates.

Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: @Jack Strange indeed. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks for including it in the answer.

Comment: I retried to do this with Microsoft Word documents and got a little further here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023396/in-git-how-to-diff-microsoft-word-documents

Comment: Wow that was nice of you! Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that **kdiff3** in your case

> Some input characters could not be converted to valid unicode. You
>   might be using the wrong codec. (e.g. UTF-8 for non UTF-8 files)....

complains because it cannot find glyph for a certain character(s) for particular font, i.e. it cannot draw it (them).

**kdiff3** has lots of configuration options that can be set in ~/.kdiff3rc configuration file ([here](http://lijw.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/conffiles/.kdiff3rc) is example). I would play with some of them related to encoding and font. For example, start with changing fonts, e.g.

```
Font=Arial
```

BTW, when you open these odt files with your editor - which readable for you font it is?

PS
Options can be also passed to kdiff3 in command line: *kdiff3 --cs "Option1=Val1" --cs "Option2=Val2"* --cs ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I'll let you know if that works, or post another question if it doesn't.

Comment: The font I was using to difftool microsoft word files is Liberation Serif.

Comment: I played around with .kdiff3rc configuration... none of the options I added seemed to make the unreadable characters readable.
I changed the comparison tool to vimdiff; and when I did git difftool on microsoft word documents, vimdiff displayed a list of files ending in .xml instead of unreadable characters.

Comment: @Jack are your files with some specific language type, e.g. Cyrillic ?

Comment: No. It's in English. BTW I just noticed the guides I have been following like http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~moy/opendocument/ only made instructions for $git diff but not $git difftool I think that's why I'm having trouble getting git difftool working but not git diff.

Comment: FYI I posted a new question on this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098218/is-git-difftool-on-binaries-possible-if-so-how-does-one-configure-it but no pressure to reply to it. Thank you so much for all your help :)