# How can I get useful git diff of files saved by Libre Office Writer, with output in the command line?

Tags: git, libreoffice, git-diff

Default version of `git diff` for default .odt files is not showing what was changed

> Binary files i/filename.odt and w/filename.odt differ

Is there a way to show what was really changed and keep file directly editable by Libre Office?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to diff .odt files with difftool? kdiff3 diff outputs unreadable characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448260/how-to-diff-odt-files-with-difftool-kdiff3-diff-outputs-unreadable-characters)

Comment: @phd I am trying to do it in the command line, with git diff - not with an external tool.

Comment: I have written a bash script that enhances Libreoffice docs into git friendly format - see https://github.com/timwiel/libreoffice2git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the flat xml format proposed by Libreoffice.

The `.fodt` file format. See [Libreoffice and version control](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Libreoffice_and_subversion) or [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264392) that provides good links.

From the link:

> If a document is saved as .fodt file it keeps the same data the .odt
> file would contain. Only that this time the data is represented as
> human-readable text (which makes the work much easier for the version
> control system) and not compressed. So saving a document as flat xml
> makes it possible to keep server space requirements and network load
> low at the relatively low cost of wasting a few kilobytes on the local
> hard disks.

Note that tiny changes will often still result in massive diffs, so it is not fully solving the problem.

Comment: It is not matching exactly the question, but it is matching exactly what I wanted. So I edited the question a bit.

Comment: The .fodt format is basically useless for diffing, because LibreOffice keeps shuffling IDs around, drowning the content changes in irrelevant metadata changes.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following to manage odt and other MS and Libre Office files in git and "git diff" them before committing.

Install the "Libre Office to text" converter:

```
$ sudo apt install unoconv catdoc
$ pip install python-pptx
```

Copy https://gitlab.com/wolframroesler/snippets/-/blob/master/git-pptx-textconv.py to a location of your choice and make it executable.

Add the following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff "doc"]
    textconv=catdoc
[diff "odt"]
    textconv=odt2txt
[diff "odp"]
    textconv=odp2txt
[diff "ods"]
    textconv=ods2txt
[diff "ppt"]
    textconv=catppt
[diff "pptx"]
    textconv=/location/of/git-pptx-textconv.py
```

Add the following to ~/.config/git/attributes (or, alternatively, to the .gitattributes file in the project root):

```
*.doc diff=doc
*.odp diff=odp
*.ods diff=ods
*.odt diff=odt
*.ppt diff=ppt
*.pptx diff=pptx
```

More details: https://gitlab.com/wolframroesler/snippets#manage-office-files-in-git

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: [As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52873589/10095231), ideally one should avoid versioning binary files,
as they make comparing, integrating and resolving conflicts
[more difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697279/10095231).

---

In git, you can configure a [diff driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_an_external_diff_driver) specific to each office file to
convert them to a plain-text representation before comparing them.

Here are a few examples of tools that can be used:

- catdoc (for Word)
- catppt (for Powerpoint)
- odt2txt (for Writer)
- xls2csv (for Excel)

First, the **file type** of each office file can be configured globally in the
`$HOME/.config/git/attributes` file:

```
*.doc binary diff=doc
*.odt binary diff=odt
*.ppt binary diff=ppt
*.xls binary diff=xls
```

Then, to globally configure the **diff driver** for each of those **file
types**:

```
git config --global diff.doc.textconv catdoc
git config --global diff.odt.textconv odt2txt
git config --global diff.ppt.textconv catppt
git config --global diff.xls.textconv xls2csv
```

Source: https://medium.com/@mbrehin/git-advanced-diff-odt-pdf-doc-xls-ppt-25afbf4f1105

Answer (score 0):

Don't store odt files in git. You can `unzip` them and store the contents instead which is XML. You might need to add newlines to the XML files as they are, IIRC, just XML one-liners.

Comment: Doing that will make in turn editing them much more inconvenient and I am not happy about storing some converted version that should be equivalent - but will not be in case of bug in the converting pipeline.

Comment: Converting in this case is just zip/unzip, it should be bug free :-)

Comment: I still worry about setup that will trigger zip/unzip at proper moments, at proper files and will overwrite iff necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For the basics, to diff the text in any zipped-xml format you can use `xmllint` to format the xml's and diff those, say you've done

```
git show master:summary.odt >${file1=`mktemp`}
git show feature:summary.odt >${file2=`mktemp`}
7z x -o ${extract1=`mktemp -d`} $file1
7z x -o ${extract2=`mktemp -d`} $file2
find $extract1 $extract2 -iname \*.xml -execdir xmllint --format {} -o {}.pretty \;
```

and you can now diff the `.pretty`'s to see what changed.  Pack that up with the usual scaffolding and you've got yourself a basic diff driver.  You can even replace the xml with the prettified xml, edit it, repack it, it all works.