# How to use different diff command for different file types by default in git

Tags: git, git-diff

I'd like to run

```
git diff
```

and have it use a different command for JSON files vs JS file vs other files. These can typically be determined by their extension (*.json, *.js, etc.).

Is there a way using .gitconfig or the like to make it use a different command when diffing different file types?

I already have the following in my .gitconfig, which is useful for diffing JSON files:

```
[difftool "jsondiff"]
        cmd = "json-diff $LOCAL $REMOTE --color=always | less -r"

[alias]
        jdiff = difftool -t jsondiff -y
```

and

```
git jdiff jsonFile.json
```

works quite well.

PS: json-diff was installed via `npm install -g json-diff`.

Comment: Explore [diff drivers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#Documentation/gitattributes.txt-String), https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+driver

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52873867/6309), you can define a diff driver for a given file extension.
The driver can be an algorithm or an external command.

With Git 2.40 (Q1 2023), the "`diff`" drivers specified by the "`diff`" attribute attached to paths can now specify which algorithm (e.g. histogram) to use.

See [commit a4cf900](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4cf900ee734ce9bb73d57c5dfbb1da4a5a88bd3), [commit 11e95e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11e95e16e8ef70c6c757d50a99f9b310e6c795f4) (20 Feb 2023) by [John Cai (`john-cai`)](https://github.com/john-cai).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ece8dc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ece8dc97ae53d08247aa283b6f299e3e5b2669db), 27 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4cf900ee734ce9bb73d57c5dfbb1da4a5a88bd3): teach diff to read algorithm from diff driver
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>

> It can be useful to specify diff algorithms per file type.
> For example, one may want to use the minimal diff algorithm for `.json` files, another for `.c` files, etc.
>
> The `diff` machinery already checks attributes for a `diff` driver.
> Teach the `diff` driver parser a new type "`algorithm`" to look for in the config, which will be used if a driver has been specified through the attributes.
>
> Enforce precedence of the diff algorithm by favoring the command line option, then looking at the driver attributes & config combination, then finally the `diff.algorithm` config.
>
> To enforce precedence order, use a new `ignore_driver_algorithm` member during options parsing to indicate the diff algorithm was set via command line args.

`gitattributes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a4cf900ee734ce9bb73d57c5dfbb1da4a5a88bd3/Documentation/gitattributes.txt#L761-L791):

> ### Setting the internal diff algorithm
>
> The diff algorithm can be set through the `diff.algorithm` config key, but
> sometimes it may be helpful to set the diff algorithm per path.
>
> For example,
> one may want to use the `minimal` diff algorithm for .json files, and the
> `histogram` for .c files, and so on without having to pass in the algorithm
> through the command line each time.
>
> First, in `.gitattributes`, assign the `diff` attribute for paths.
>
> ```ini
> *.json diff=<name>
> ```
>
> Then, define a "diff..algorithm" configuration to specify the diff
> algorithm, choosing from `myers`, `patience`, `minimal`, or `histogram`.
>
> ```ini
> [diff "<name>"]
> algorithm = histogram
> ```
>
> This diff algorithm applies to user facing diff output like git-diff(1),
> git-show(1) and is used for the `--stat` output as well. The merge machinery
> will not use the diff algorithm set through this method.
>
> NOTE: If `diff.<name>.command` is defined for path with the
> `diff=<name>` attribute, it is executed as an external diff driver
> (see above), and adding `diff.<name>.algorithm` has no effect, as the
> algorithm is not passed to the external diff driver.